# VUE. VUEX. Binding Input Field To Output List

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have:

- a `List`
- a `Button`
- a `Text-Field`

I'd like the `List` to incorporate the `Text` from the `Text-Field`, on each `Button`-Click.

I know that VUE(X) is able to do some Magic.

How do I connect the pieces properly?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The Vue.js documentation is very good and will probably answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vuex. Create a store with `list: []` 
Then on button click, trigger an action that will commit a mutation and will add an item to the list...

index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   <input type="text" v-model="newItem"/>
   <button @click="addItem(newItem)">add</button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      newItem: ''
    }
  },
  methods: mapActions(['addItem'])
}
</script>
```

store.js

```
list: []
```

actions.js

```
addItem: ({commit}, data) => {
  commit('ADD_ITEM', data)
}
```

mutations.js

```
[ADD_ITEM] (state, data) {
  state.list.push(data)
}
```

something like this...

The list will be autoupdated right after adding new item if you use `mapGetters` to get list items.